# How to stop Office 365 update banner?

Tags: office365

So Office 365 has recently started displaying a banner urging me to "GET THE NEW OFFICE". I don't want to, at least not right now. But every time I open one of the apps or a new document, I see the same annoying banner.

What can I check or uncheck or set or unset or whatever to keep this thing from popping up all the time? I haven't found anything in the application options or in my account settings online.

[image]

Windows 8.1

Excel version 15.0.4771.1004

Answer (score 2):

I just got hit with this at work, and here's the solution I found which worked:

1. Exit all your MS Office programs (check the taskbar for Skype or any other minimized apps)
2. Run **regedit** to edit the registry
3. Navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\Updates**
   *(your version number may vary)*
4. In the right pane, you will see an option for **UpgradeAdvertised**
5. Change that value from 1 to 0

And that will get rid of the banner.

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable Updates as other's have suggested, as that will prevent actual updates from being installed as well. -- Despite the wording on the button, this isn't an "Update", it's actually an "Upgrade" in disguise, and it's very misleading. -- But you ***can*** disable the upgrade without disabling updates.

For the benefit of other readers, let's differentiate between the two:

A regular update looks like this -- these are good, you want these.
[image: Regular Update]

Versus the "Upgrade" prompt, which looks like this -- this is bad (and misleading!) -- you want to disable only this one.
[image: Vague and misleading Upgrade Prompt]

**To disable the automatic upgrade:** just download and install this Microsoft "Easy Fix":

- [How do I keep on running Office 365 ProPlus 2013?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3097292)

[image: The link is about halfway down the page, in a big blue button labeled "Download".]

The page also has some addition details for IT admins on how to prevent it for an organization using group policy editor, and manual registry fixes as well.  But for individuals, the easiest way to do this is to just run the easy fix. :-)

The bad news is, if you accidentally did get tricked into installing the upgrade, the only supported path for going back to 2013 is a complete uninstall / reinstall cycle (and if you want to avoid being tricked again, I recommend installing the easy fix after you complete that cycle).

Comment: The "easy fix" is the only solution that's worked for me.

Comment: I'm having the problem in the first picture. See [Disable Office “UPDATES AVAILABLE” notification](https://superuser.com/q/1280203/256296). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In one of Office apps, go to page `File` - `Account` there is a section, named `Product Information`. There should be a button like `Update Options` above `Office Updates`, with that you can disable updates ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOsIj.png)). I suppose, then it will not notify you to update...
Anyway what is your Office version (it can be found near the mentioned button)? I've never get notifications like this yet.

Comment: Nope, that has no effect. And I've added system and application info to my original post.

Comment: Don't do that, it will disable ALL updates -- this is not an update prompt, it's an upgrade prompt.  See my answer for details on how to disable the upgrade without disabling other updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the date when Office triggers the banner.  The other methods work until the next Windows "so called update" gets installed, then it sets them right back where they were.

I can't remember the exact place in the registry where this trigger date is located, but when I find it I'll pass it along.  On my other Wni10 box I set it to expire in 2024 and that worked, permanently.

Tom